# Windows 7 looping in repair mode

Tags: windows-7, boot, debian

After a power outage one week ago, my Windows 7 always enter the repair tool and fails to repair everytime. Everytime I try to boot using windows (dual-boot with Debian stretch), it just repeats the same process.

At the end of the process, when I click Finish, the computer just powers off.

**Additional info**

My DVD player is not working properly either, and somehow, I never managed to boot using an USB drive, all my OSs were installed using DVDs prior to its malfunction.

My partitions are as the following:

- One 125GB for my Debian installation
- One 125GB for the Win7 installation
- One 250GB where I install my Win7 applications (non OS-related applications)
- One 1TB where I put my installers, game installs, medias, documents on a completely separate hard drive

**What I have already tried**

- When I let the repair process as is, it happens as I described above
- I tried cancelling the process and I could access more tools, I have used the command line to attempt a CHKDSK on restart on the C: drive, and when I restarted, it didn't go into CHKDSK

**What I didn't try yet**

- I haven't tried restoring Windows to a previous state yet, would it work?
- I don't have any ways of reinstalling the OS yet (no install disk in physical or ISO form), and I would want it as a last resort as it's most likely to mess up with the GRUB, and I don't have the ways to fix the GRUB anyway

Comment: See this page....https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/139576-startup-repair-infinite-loop-recovery.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I tried restoring the system, it said there were no restoration point.

I entered the command prompt again and used CHKDSK /f on the drive without restarting. Now it's booting normally again.

Answer (score 1):

> I haven't tried restoring Windows to a previous state yet, would it work?

This is the last remaining solution, judging from your question.

Comment: maybe there are other solutions I'm not aware of yet (pretty sure there is, I don't always tamper directly with my win7 OS)